# What's Relay's relationship to Flux?

Tags: relayjs

Currently Flux is only mentioned once in the Relay docs (deep in the API reference for Relay.Store). I was initially very confused about the relationship between the Relay and Flux. I've seen some small unofficial explanations, e.g.

> Relay is an implementation of the Flux pattern.

(from [Relay issue #168](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/168))

What's the final word on Relay's relationship to Flux?

Comment: Moved to SO from Github https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/747#issuecomment-174052244

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Relay currently supports fetching and rendering data fetched from a GraphQL server. For some applications this can obviate the need for something like Flux, since all data may come from the server. For applications that also need to maintain *complex* local state - i.e. beyond the scope of component-local state - we recommend using Flux (in particular [Redux](http://redux.js.org/)) in addition to Relay.

Support for managing local state (non-server data) is on the roadmap for Relay - see https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/114.