# Relay Modern with Redux integration

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, relaymodern

I have reached the case where i have to handle with the client state between `react` components meaning that i need to pass data from child component to parent(found workaround for neighbouring components).

1. Do you think Redux implementation with Relay Modern is a match and worth having multiple stores?(or it is a good practice?)
2. It is a best practice if i update the backend and getting the data back on other `react` components(Relay query) when it is needed?(this sort of data it is needed only by current user so it is not so relevant to app context)

I want to have a drawer which applies filters globally to all app.

Comment: Answering your first question, I don't believe it's a good thing to have multiple stores, I wouldn't do that, but still the Redux Store is better manageable than Relay Modern store, even because it has no store, it's quite different. I didn't find a good way of doing that yet, but still looking for it. Did you managed to try to dispatch to Redux everytime you execute a fragment or something like that? How did it worked out?

Comment: I didn't use redux for state management. I used only relay Store, actually a good workaround for me was to move the Relay's  <QueryRenderer /> component to my parent components. I use optimisticUpdater and updater functions and update my Relay store and change/update all queries, this method looks quite clean for me.

Answer (score 0):

1) Maintainer of Relay says yes https://stackoverflow.com/a/34958818/3739087 (but I would do everything to find a solution without implementing second store)

2) Not sure if I get it right, but you should always request just the data you need. So yes, it is a best practice.